# handling special characters e.g. accents in R

Tags: r, character

I am doing some  web scraping of names into a dataframe

For a name such as "Tomáš Rosický, I get a result "TomÃ¡Å¡ RosickÃ½"

I tried

```
Encoding("TomÃ¡Å¡ RosickÃ½") #  with latin1 response
```

but was not sure where to go from there to get the original name with accents back. Played around with iconv without success

I would be satisfied (and might even prefer) an output of "Tomas Rosicky"

Comment: How did you read the data.frame? Usually you can supply an encoding parameter such as `fileEncoding` to `read.table`. And as @Hong Ooi answered, UTF-8 seems to be the encoding you need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've read in a page encoded in UTF-8. if `x` is your column of names, use `Encoding(x) <- "UTF-8"`.

Answer (score 7):

You should use this:

```
df$colname <- iconv(df$colname, from="UTF-8", to="LATIN1")
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation, too?

Answer (score 5):

To do a correct read of the file use the scan function:

```
namb <- scan(file='g:/testcodering.txt', fileEncoding='UTF-8',
what=character(), sep='\n', allowEscapes=T)
cat(namb)
```

This also works:

```
namc <- readLines(con <- file('g:/testcodering.txt', "r",
encoding='UTF-8')); close(con)
cat(namc)
```

This will read the file with the correct accents

Answer (score 3):

A way to export accents correctly:

```
enc2utf8(as(dataframe$columnname, "character"))
```